# numbering the textviews

Tags: android, textview

I am new in android programming.
I am creating a app where I supposed to use multiple textviews. Number of TextViews go on changing according to number of records fetched from database.
Here, i was trying to number textviews as textView1, textView2, textView3,... 
but as i am unaware about the number of records, i can not define them statically
is there any way to do so dynamically
like we do in PHP
e.g

```
$count = 1;
if(condition)
{
    textView.$count;
    $count++;
}
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a List of TextViews and populate it dynamically

```
List<TextView> list = new LinkedList<TextView>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the total number of record at runtime and create the TextView in a loop for each textView  and finally ad it to the current layout.

For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<data.size;i++){

TextView tv=new TextView(this);
tv.setText(data.get(i));
currentLayput.addView(tv);

}
```

where **data is some vector or Arraylist** in which you can store the data from database.